# Print output in scripted curl - Python

Tags: python, curl, printing, subprocess, iteration

need some help with this.
Already made an iterative script in Python to execute a curl at the same URL but with multiple PORTS, but I'm strugglin with the desired output.

I'm getting 1 of this for each PORT atm.

```
<!-- current output -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Length Required</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Length Required</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

What I need is to clean the output as much as possible as I'm only interested in printing the **URL+PORT** and **HTTP_STATUS_CODE** in each execution. Or Something close to this:

```
<!-- desired output
CURL_AT=http://www.isuckatpython/shootmyself.com:8080
HTTP_STATUS_CODE=411 -->
```

This is my current script

```
import subprocess
import os

port_list = [8080, 8090, 8091, 8092, 8093, 8094, 8095]
for i in port_list:
    i = str(i)
    subprocess.call(["curl", "-s", "-X", "POST", "http://www.isuckatpython/shootmyself.com:", i])
```

Hope I was clear enough.

Kind regards,
Alem.

Comment: if there is nothing running at a specific port then you will not get a status code from curl rather you will get something like `curl: (7) Failed to connect to <url> port 8080: Connection refused` **Error**. What about in that case?

Comment: You might want to try [HTTPie](https://httpie.org/) instead of curl.

Comment: @TomiAarnio Thanks for your help. But I'm afraid thats not an option right now as I'm not allowed to upgade current Python version (2.7 atm).

Comment: @mohammedwazeem In that case, I don't know, perhaps print that message instead of the HTTP Status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the expected output in this way.

```
import subprocess


port_list = [8080, 8090, 8091, 8092, 8093, 8094, 8095]
host = "http://www.isuckatpython/shootmyself.com:"

for port in port_list:
    result = subprocess.Popen('curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" '+ host + str(port),
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output, error = result.communicate()
    output = output.decode('utf-8')
    if output != '000':
        # if curl:  Failed to connect to <url> port gives "000"
        print("CURL_AT="+host+str(port))
        print("HTTP_STATUS_CODE="+output)
    else:
        print("curl: Failed to connect to {0} port {1}: Connection ".format(host, port))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm getting this error when executed: NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined, result = subprocess.run('curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" '+ host + str(port)

Comment: @alem Please `import subprocess` module. you are getting this error because you didn't import subprocess module. import it and try again.

Comment: you were right, that was missing, now I'm getting this message: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'. I was diggin around and found that subprocess.run() function only exists in Python 3.5 and newer. Im currently using 2.7

Comment: @alem I have updated the answer. Please have a look at it

Comment: it seems it works fine. Thank you so much for your effort and help!

Comment: You got it! Thanks again ;)